# Manipulate element inside Iframe in Vite React project?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, vite

Now I am writing a vite application which use iframe and show the content from another https web page. My question is that is it possible to remove some element rendering inside the iframe using React or is there any alternative ways if the React is hard to manipulate the iframe content.

I wanna manipulate the html content inside iframe at the following react component

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import Spinner from "@/components/common/spinner";

const IFrame = ({ src }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div className="relative h-full w-full">
            {isLoading && (
                <div className="w-full bg-white absolute inset-0">
                    <Spinner />
                </div>
            )}
            <iframe
                src={src}
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen=""
                id="frame-id"
                webkitallowfullscreen="true"
                mozallowfullscreen="true"
                oallowfullscreen="true"
                msallowfullscreen="true"
                className="w-full h-full"
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default IFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the iframe's content with a useRef Hook and manipulate it with plain javascript.

```js
const IFrame = ({ src }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const ref = useRef(null)
    
    const manipulateIframe = () => {
       // get elements from iframe document
       const testElement = ref.current?.contentWindow.document.getElementById('test');
    }

    return (
        <div className="relative h-full w-full">
            {isLoading && (
                <div className="w-full bg-white absolute inset-0">
                    <Spinner />
                </div>
            )}
            <iframe
                ref={ref}
                src={src}
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen=""
                id="frame-id"
                webkitallowfullscreen="true"
                mozallowfullscreen="true"
                oallowfullscreen="true"
                msallowfullscreen="true"
                className="w-full h-full"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I am using React Vite and I tried like you mentioned, but I faced with 

react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:5173" from accessing a cross-origin frame.